# DropDownList Incorrect SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

`DropDownList` control is returning the wrong item.

My code performs a specific action with the `SelectedItem` when `DropDownList.SelectedValue = -1`.

When testing the code, I pick item `A` at `index = 2`.  The resulting `DropDownList.SelectedItem = "A"`.  Good so far.

But I pick item `B` at `index = 3`.  The resulting `DropDownList.SelectedItem = "A"`.  According to the debugger, `DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 2` in both cases.

What causes the `SelectedIndex` to always take on the same value?

Note: When I pick items `C` through `Z`, they return the proper `SelectedText` and `SelectedIndex`.

```
if(Int32.Parse(dropdown.SelectedValue).Equals(-1))
{
    // Do something with the selected item
    DoThis(dropdown.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It should be `dropdown.SelectedIndex == -1`

Comment: Let's see what your doing in Page_Load().

Comment: @RickS Page_Load() shouldn't make much of a difference.  The DoThis() saves a value to my DB, so the value should be OK.  Value of both items is the same.  But index is being returned as the same as well.

Comment: I was asking because many times on postback the dropdown list is repopulated therefore you would see the first entry always selected.

Comment: @RickS Good point - I realized I do repopulate my dropdown list in Page_Load().  Everything is reinitialized in the same order with the same indices.  So wouldn't the proper index be selected still?

Comment: No, you need to wrap the code in `if (!IsPostBack)`

Comment: @RickS I have this: if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               PopulateDropDownList();
            }

Comment: I updated the original post: Note: When I pick items `C` through `Z`, they return the proper `SelectedText` and `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: @RickS Does it make a difference if the PopulateDropDownList is called _after_ the code block in the post?  I do this update the dropdown list, but I'm guessing it has no impact on the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When several items of a DropDownList have the same value, selecting any of them will turn out as if the first item with that value was selected. You should modify the duplicate values to make each one unique.

Comment: To fix it I set a unique ID for each item like so: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20044730/5144249