# Convert numeric List 1,2,3,4 to Alphabetic List A,B,C,D

Tags: c#

I have a `List<int>` that contains incremental integers like 1,2,3,4 .
How can I convert the 'list' . I'm looking for an algorithm or code to change numbers to 'corresponding' letters.

```
 List<string>
```

**From:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5**

**To :
A, B, C, D, E.... AA, AB etc.**

Change the increments from 1,2,3  to A, B, C

Comment: What have you tried so far? Probably a look at a codepage (like [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) could help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert character to its alphabet integer position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044730/convert-character-to-its-alphabet-integer-position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple math. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    var intList = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);
    var alphaList = intList.Select(x => ToAlpha(x));
    foreach (var x in alphaList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

private static string ToAlpha(int i)
{
    string result = "";
    do
    {
        result = (char)((i-1) % 26 + 'A') + result;
        i = (i-1)/26;
    } while (i > 0);
    return result;
}
```